# verifying if this vector result is true

Tags: vectors, recreational-mathematics

So, the question is as follows :

If $p,q,r$ are mutually perpendicular vectors such that $|p| = |q| = |r| \neq 0$.

then, is $(p \cdot x)p +(q \cdot x)q +(r \cdot x)r =|p|^2 x$? where $x$ is not a null vector.

my approach:

since  $p,q,r$ are mutually perpendicular vectors then we can take them along the $x,y,z$ coordinate axes and it is obvious that the result is true. But I do not know if this can be done without loss in generality. Is the result true? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not true. Why would you expect this to be true?

Comment: @Don Thousand I came across a question which used this result without proving it. can you give a counter example to this ?

Comment: As stated, this doesn't make any sense. Over what exactly is the sum, and where $q$ and $r$ are needed? I'm really sorry if this is a bit blunt, but if you can't even copy the question exactly, how do you hope to understand possible (but unlikely) answers?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I have edited question I hope it now makes sense.

Comment: welcome to MSE!  you should learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math -- i have done it for you this time.  anyway the statement is true and it hinges on the fact that $|p| = |q| = |r|$, so in a sense you are rotating the frame and then rescaling your units.  (BTW it is also true for $x=0$ null vector.)

Comment: @antkam thanks for your support

Comment: Now, it makes sense, and it's true. $x$ is the sum of the projections on three mutually perpendicular directions, indeed. It's a three-dimensional space.